# Bokeh not displaying plot even after converting X and Y values into NumPy arrays and using a DateTime axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, bokeh

Bokeh is not displaying my plot. I will give the whole code but mark the area I am suspicious of with Python comments.

```
import pandas
import numpy

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.statmuse.com/money/ask/bitcoin+value+graph+2020-2021+monthly")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
html = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "kaojVddNm5wDHXzg63Rp").get_attribute("outerHTML")
driver.close()

df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_html(html)[0][::-1])

df["DATE"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
dates = df["DATE"].to_numpy(dtype="datetime64[M]")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=dates, close=list(df["CLOSE"])))

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ Suspicious area where the error might be ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=1200, tools="", toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type="datetime", x_axis_location="above",
           background_fill_color="#efefef", x_range=(dates[9], dates[18]))

p.line(x="date", y="close", source=source)

select = figure(title="Drag the middle and edges of the selection box to change the range above",
                plot_height=130, plot_width=1200, y_range=p.y_range,
                x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type=None,
                tools="", toolbar_location=None, background_fill_color="#efefef")

# ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ Suspicious area where the error might be ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

range_tool = RangeTool(x_range=p.x_range)

range_tool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_tool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.line(x="date", y="close", source=source)
select.ygrid.line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_tool)
select.toolbar.active_multi = range_tool

output_file("btc_price_interactive.html", title="Bitcoin Price Chart")
show(column(p, select))
```

When running the code, I see nothing but two blank grey plots and a title that I specified in the "Suspicious Area".

[picture of the resulting plots that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THq7U.png)

I then booted up the Edge Console and saw that there were several errors, 5 to be exact. 4 of them were warnings which stated
[bokeh] could not set initial ranges
and last one was an error which stated
Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid bbox {x0: NaN, y0: 27, x1: NaN, y1: 125}

There is this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874639/bokeh-not-displaying-plot-for-pandas) that I found which provides two solutions for my error to work. I had already implemented the second solution beforehand as you can see -- I have already converted the datetime values to datetime NumPy arrays and even though the values are strings, the axis for the plots is a datetime axis which means it should work as stated in the second solution but it doesn't work.

I will be extremely grateful if you could help me fix my mistakes. (its probably like an obvious mistake like a spelling mistake which I am unable to locate)

Comment: This is really guessing, but because of the `invalid bbox {x0: NaN, y0: 27, x1: NaN, y1: 125}` and your `x_range` in figure `p` I believe, your DataFrame has no valid data. It looks like `dates[9]` and `dates[18]` is `None` or `NaN`. Could you please update your question and add some lines of your DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, something is wrong with your data. I copy'n'past your code and created some dummy data, which is working fine.

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

#dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':np.random.randint(100,200,20)}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=20, freq='M'))
df.index.name = 'date'

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# figures
p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=1200, tools="", toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type="datetime", x_axis_location="above",
           background_fill_color="#efefef", x_range=(df.index[9], df.index[18]))

p.line(x="date", y="close", source=source)

select = figure(title="Drag the middle and edges of the selection box to change the range above",
                plot_height=130, plot_width=1200, y_range=p.y_range,
                x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type=None,
                tools="", toolbar_location=None, background_fill_color="#efefef")
range_tool = RangeTool(x_range=p.x_range)

range_tool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_tool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.line(x="date", y="close", source=source)
select.ygrid.line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_tool)
select.toolbar.active_multi = range_tool

show(column(p, select))
```

**Output**

[image: range tool]

**Further readings**

1. The bokeh documentation has an example for the use of the [range tool](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/range_tool.html) with some [sampledata](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/sampledata.html#sampledata-stocks).
2. It looks like you are trying to plot a candlestick plot. Bokeh docs has an [example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html) for this, too.
3. On SO exists a modification of the candlestick example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876637/plotting-candlestick-and-volume-candels-in-bokeh), which can be modified with a range-tool easily.